# How do I reset/revert Personas in Firefox 3.6?

Tags: firefox, personas

How can a selected Personas be set back/disabled in [Firefox 3.6](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mozilla_Firefox_3.6)?

I have downloaded and installed Firefox 3.6 and selected [a Personas](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/persona/66575) (lightweight themes/toolbar skins). However the content of the download status bar at the buttom is no longer readable. How can the Personas be removed/disabled such that the original state after the installation is restored?

Comment: (I am documenting this problem and its resolution as I used far too much time on it. I hope others will save some time.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The original state can be restored this way:

menu Tools/Add-ons/Themes/click "Default 3.6"/press button "Use Theme"/<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd>

A restart of Firefox is not required.

Comment: alt+f4 or click 'close'